# Transactions not working for SubSonic under Oracle?

Tags: oracle, subsonic, transactions, commit

The following code sample works perfectly under SQL Server 2005:

```
using (TransactionScope ts = new TransactionScope()) {
            using (SharedDbConnectionScope scope = new SharedDbConnectionScope()) {
                MyTable t = new MyTable();
                t.Name = "Test";
                t.Comments = "Comments 123";
                t.Save();
                ts.Complete();
            }
        }
```

But under Oracle 10g it throws a "ORA-02089: COMMIT is not allowed in a subordinate session" error. If I only execute the code inside the SharedDbConnectionScope block then everything works OK, but obviously I won't be able to execute operations under a transaction, thus risking data corruption.

This is only a small sample of what my real application does. I'm not sure as to what may be causing this behavior; anyone out there care to shed some light on this issue please?

---

here's the config:

```
<configSections> <section name="SubSonicService" type="SubSonic.SubSonicSection, SubSonic" requirePermission="false"/> </configSections> <connectionStrings> <add name="OracleConnection" connectionString="Data Source=XE;User Id=test;Password=test;"/> </connectionStrings> <SubSonicService defaultProvider="OracleProvider"> <providers> <clear/> <add name="OracleProvider" type="SubSonic.OracleDataProvider, SubSonic" connectionStringName="OracleConnection" generatedNamespace="OracleTest" /> </providers> </SubSonicService>
```

Answer (score 1):

[Looking](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=488477) [up](http://bytes.com/topic/oracle/answers/806386-oracle-jdbc-sqlexception-commit-not-allowed-subordinate-session) that specific error message suggests that something may be trying to explicitly or implicitly COMMIT.

If you look at [OracleDataProvider.cs](http://github.com/daveneeley/SubSonic-2.0/blob/master/SubSonic/DataProviders/OracleDataProvider.cs), inside GetInsertSql(Query qry) an explicit COMMIT is issued:

```
    if (retrieveID)
        insertSQL.AppendFormat("  RETURNING {0} INTO :lllhhhmmm; COMMIT; END; ", qry.Schema.PrimaryKey.ColumnName);
```

COMMIT is also called in ExecuteScalar() in the same file. Do you still see the problem when you are updating records instead of inserting them?

Comment: I still see a problem, only a different one when updating. I get an InvalidOperationException with the message: "Invalid operation. The connection is closed." The only difference in the code used is adding this line of code:

MyTable t = new MyTable(8);

Passing the Id of a valid record in the table instead of using a parameterless constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing

```
using (TransactionScope ts = new TransactionScope())
```

and use only the SharedDbConnectionScope, like this:

```
        SharedDbConnectionScope scope = new SharedDbConnectionScope();
        using (scope) {
            MyTable t = new MyTable();
            t.Name = "Test";
            t.Comments = "Comments 123";
            t.Save();
            scope.commit();
        }
```